# How to change MSCRMSandboxService target name?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

In one of my Full MS Dynamics365 on-premises Servers I have changed the domain name and processed as documented and everything works Except MSCRMSandboxService which doesn't work and I get the following Error:

> The program Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.HostService.exe, with the assigned process ID 9336, could not authenticate locally by using the target name MSCRMSandboxService/SERVERNAME.MYOLDDOMAINNAME.local. The target name used is not valid. A target name should refer to one of the local computer names, for example, the DNS host name.

Try a different target name.

I searched everywhere and searched every document possible , no luck. The question is simply:

**How to change the MSCRMSandboxService Target name?**

For your reference I use 9.1 version.

Best